# Will ROS able to support linux mint in the future?

Tags: ros, linuxmint

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I know that linux mint 12 is based on ubuntu 11.10, so it can install ros-fuerte ( I have tried to install it).

Is ROS can always support linux mint for later update?

Thank you~

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/32915/will-ros-able-to-support-linux-mint-in-the-future?/) by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2570 on 2012-04-29

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Mint is "experimental". I doubt it will ever be officially "supported".

How well "experimental" platforms work depends on whether they have an active user community contributing fixes for `rosdep` and other issues. People [have reported](http://answers.ros.org/questions/scope:all/sort:activity-desc/tags:linuxmint/page:1/) various problems with Mint. I can't tell how well they have been resolved.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2012-04-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1